# ESLint, treat React variable as unused

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I've just updated my project to React 17 which doesn't require `React` to be imported in every file. I also disabled `react/jsx-uses-react` and `react/react-in-jsx-scope` rules. The first one was preventing eslint from complaining that `React` variable is unnecessary. But now when it's really unnecessary, even though the rule is disabled and there is no error when I delete `React` import, it doesn't say that it is unused. What may be the reason, are there any other rules that prevent ESLint from treating `React` as unused? I made an empty react project recently and there this import was marked as unused, so why is it not here

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

This answer is not related to ESLint.

Some details on the project under test:

- The project is configured (`tsconfig.json`) to use «New JSX transform».
  Please, see: [React 17 JSX Factories | Announcing TypeScript 4.1 | TypeScript](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#react-17-jsx-factories).
- The TypeScript source code file contains a JSX fragment and the **deliberately redundant** `React` import (`import React from "react";`).

## Solution

I have noticed that after upgrading TypeScript to **the 4.2.2 version**, the TypeScript compiler started to report the appropriate compilation error:

> TS6133: 'React' is declared but its value is never read.

The error message points to the problematic source code line:

```
import React from "react";
```